# when i download cshtml file from my site it will give failed - forbidden error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

that type of error give explorer when  I download  .cshtml file [display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1kIW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

cshtml file is not allowed by mime types by default. these are supposed to be processed by the razor view handlers. if your web site is only serving these files as static content then you need to add these as mime types in IIS config